# How to convert non palette transparent image to palette image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to convert non palette transparent image to palette image?

I found example : 
http://nadiana.com/pil-tips-converting-png-gif

But I need to transparent index to be first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  think PIL can give you this level of control.

I can think of only two ways of doing that: Using GIMP (there are GIMP-Python bindings) - or manipulate the final GIF or PNG file manually.  I don't think even GIMP can give you this sort of fine graned control over an image's pallette in a programatic way.

Manipulating the palette manually is not hard, since you will b dealing -both in GIF and PNG formats, with fixed binary structues at the file headers - it may be the more suitable way of doing it.